# Force screen redraw other than using removeChild() and then addChild() to get image to update?

Tags: actionscript-3, redraw, addchild

Here's some code I created as an answer to another question. It pulls a library item out of the library and puts it on stage programmatically. No big deal, except that in order to get the image displayed on the screen to actually update, I had to removeChild() and then addChild() it back. Is there another way to force the screen to redraw?

```
var currentImage:int = 1;
var MAX_IMAGES:int = 3;

MC_prevButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
MC_nextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goForward);

var imageClip:MovieClip = new Image_1();
var thumbClip:MovieClip = new Thumb_1();

imageClip.x = thumbClip.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
imageClip.y = thumbClip.y = stage.stageHeight/2;



addChildAt(thumbClip, 0);
addChildAt(imageClip, 1);

setImages(currentImage);

function goBack(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (currentImage) currentImage--;
    setImages(currentImage);
}

function goForward(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (currentImage < MAX_IMAGES) currentImage++;
    setImages(currentImage);
}

function setImages(imageNumber){
    trace("Setting image number: " + imageNumber);

    var LibraryImage:Class = getDefinitionByName("Image_" + imageNumber) as Class;
    if (LibraryImage){
        removeChild(imageClip);
        imageClip = new LibraryImage();
        addChildAt(imageClip, 1);
    }
    var LibraryThumb:Class = getDefinitionByName("Thumb_" + imageNumber) as Class;
    if (LibraryThumb){
        removeChild(thumbClip);
        thumbClip = new LibraryThumb();
        addChildAt(thumbClip, 0);
    }

    imageClip.x = thumbClip.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
    imageClip.y = thumbClip.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
}
```

Note that in this example, this code is on frame 1 of the timeline, and that it's a 1-frame FLA file

Answer (score 0):

Try calling updateAfterEvent() at the end of your forward and back methods:

```
function goForward(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (currentImage < MAX_IMAGES) currentImage++;
    setImages(currentImage);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but nah, that's not it. updateAferEvent() is used to force a screen redraw within an event loop for things that have to be updated before the screen is naturally updated on enter frame. In this case, we're not in an enter frame loop and there's plenty of time to refresh the screen after setImage() is run.

Comment: Actually looking at it again you and I are misunderstanding the problem :)

When you call `addChildAt(imageClip, 1);` in AS3 it adds the image at level 1 but does not remove the image as in AS2. Instead the new image is added at level 2. If your images are the same size it will look like nothing is happening as the top (first) image hides the rest. Set the alpha of all the images to .5 to see that they are being added, just behind it each other. If you change `addChildAt` to `addChild` the image will be added on top of the others.

Comment: Hey thanks for sticking with this! Well, actually because I'm first calling removeChild() in the above code example (which works, it's just ugly), the child is being removed before being added back on the stage. In the version (that doesn't work) there is no addChild() beyond what happens upon initialization. I add the child at the beginning, and then just hold a reference to it in the imageClip variable, which I later set to a new library item with the setImages() function.

Comment: Not exactly. You're removing an instance of a MovieClip. Then you create a completely new instance of a MovieClip that is defined in the Library. It is not like you're placing that exact MovieClip from the Library on to the stage. A class is a blueprint for an object not a reference to an object.